# Passing record id via Link to Visualforce detail page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

```
<apex:outputLink value="/!{opportunity.id}">{!opportunity.Name}</apex:outputLink>
```

I am creating 2 pages in VF. One page to display a list of custom object records from a dynamic search. This is complete.

I need to now create a custom VF page to display a single record information when a user clicks on a link on the list page. I know we can use an output link like the one shown above.

Assuming I have built the detail page (assume its path is "apex/customDetailPage"), how would I go about modifying this link. Because my detail page will need the selected record id passed to it I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it just like this:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/customDetailPage?id={!opportunity.id}">
  {!opportunity.Name}
</apex:outputLink>
```

Assuming that your custom page checks for the `id` parameter to establish which record it should be working with.

You can also use the [`$Page` global variable option as described here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_variables_functions.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/pages_variables_functions.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) which should mean it'll look something like this:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.customDetailPage}?id={!opportunity.id}">
  {!opportunity.Name}
</apex:outputLink>
```